# Separate and Solve $u_x+2u_{tx}-10u_{tt}=0$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I came across a question requesting that the PDE below along with its boundary condition be separated:

$$u_x+2u_{tx}-10u_{tt}=0$$
$$u(0,t)=0, u_x(L,t)=0$$

Which I was able to do using the method described below:

$$u(x,t)=X(x)T(t)$$

Thus:
$$u_x=X'T$$
$$u_{tx}=X'T'$$
$$u_{tt}=XT''$$
Substituting these into the original PDE and simplifying gave me:
$$\frac{X'}{X}=\frac{10T''}{T+2T'}=-\lambda$$
This thus permitted me to split the PDE into 2 ODEs;
$$X'+\lambda X=0$$
$$10T''+2\lambda T'+\lambda T=0$$

I was also able to split the boundary conditions:
$$u(0,t)=X(0)T(t)=0$$
$$u_x(L,t)=X'(L)T(t)=0$$

This gives me:
$$X(0)=0$$
$$X'(L)=0$$
Since $T(t)=0$ would be trivial (thus not desirable)

Now my problem is how to solve the BVP below without getting a trivial equation:
$$X'+\lambda X=0$$
$$X(0)=0$$
$$X'(L)=0$$

Comment: The last BVP has the *only* trivial solution (since the general solution to $X'+\lambda X=0$ is $X(x) = C e^{-\lambda x}$, $C$ is a constant). Maybe there is a misprint in the initial problem?

Comment: You might have swapped $x$ and $t$ in the original problem. If $X$ obeys the second order ODE you found for $T$, then you obtain a nontrivial solution to your boundary value problem.

Comment: Could it possibly have been $u_{xx}$ rather than $u_x$ in the PDE? This would make the separated ODE as  second-order and solvable.

Comment: @Semiclassical separation of variables for the case $u_{xx}$ instead of $u_x$ is less trivial and definitely wont produce the same ODEs.

Comment: @Voliar et al (FritsVeerman & Semiclassical) you guys just confirmed my suspicion. Thanks